# How to retrieve previous values from HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following code where I'm reading from a text file. The text file i as follows:

```
111 Laptop 500 10
222 Mobile 120 8
333 Notebook 4 100
444 Chocolates 3 50
555 Guitar 199 5
666 LenovoLaptop 470 10
777 HPLaptop 450 10
888 SonyVAIO 525 5
```

If the user enters `ID` as `111`, the following should be the output:

```
111 Laptop 500 10
666 LenovoLaptop 470 10
777 HPLaptop 450 10
888 SonyVAIO 525 5
```

I'm storing the the contents of the text file in a HashMap. Here is the code:

```
public void comparableItems(String ID)
{
    File f = new File("C://Class/items.txt");
    HashMap<String, Item> map = new HashMap<String, Item>();

    try
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);

        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            String line = scan.nextLine();
            String temp[] = line.split(" ");

            Item it = new Item(temp[0], temp[1], Double.parseDouble(temp[2]), Integer.parseInt(temp[3]));

            map.put(it.itemID, it);
        }
        if(map.containsKey(ID))
        {
            Item item = map.get(ID);
            if(item.price>=item.price+100 && item.price<=item.price-100)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the Item class:

```
public class Item 
{
String itemID;
String itemName;
double price;
int quantity;

public Item(String itemID, String itemName, double price, int quantity)
{
    this.itemID = itemID;
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.price = price;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public void printItemDetails()
{
    System.out.println("ID\tItemName\tUnitPrice\tQuantity");
    System.out.println("===================================================");

    System.out.println(this.itemID+ "\t" +this.itemName+ "\t" +this.price+ "\t"+this.quantity);
}
}
```

How do I get the desired output? I'm in the learning stages of Java Collections. So please bear with me.

Can someone help me here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would entering `111` result in the list you've provided? Is the `ID` not unique? I would expect the result to be `111 Laptop 500 10`. It seems like you'd want to enter a phrase like `*laptop*` to get the results that are all laptops.

Comment: @bblincoe I want to search using the item ID. (which is assumed as unique)

Comment: If that's the case, wouldn't the result simply be `111 Laptop 500 10`?

Comment: Do you mean `map.get("111")` ?

Comment: @bblincoe I get it. But I'd like to display the items that are near the price range of `111 Laptop 500 10`. The price for the `Laptop` being `500`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've learnt how to use `map.get("111")`. But that's not what I want.

Comment: You really need to edit your question to reflect what you want to do.

Comment: You'll need to go through your `HashMap`s `values` and grab the price with a `getPrice()` method in your `Item` class. You'll then need to include some logic to compare the entry you grabbed (e.g. `111 Laptop 500 10`) with the price of all other entries.

Comment: @betseyb I've included what I want as output in the question. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yes, you don't describe what that output means, except in your comments.

Comment: @bblincoe Yes. I'm really not able to work about the logic. The logic's the part I cannot get at all. That's I posted in stackoverflow so that someone could help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Map` isn't doing you much good.  Since you know what reference item ID you're looking for before you even parse the file, you could just capture that item when (and if) you see it during the parse.  You do need some kind of collection to hold all the other items, but a `List` would be a better choice for this particular task.

In any case, the thrust of your question seems to be about examining all the *other* items you parse from the file.  For this, you want to iterate over the `Map`'s `values()` view (and to get your comparisons right):

```
for (Item otherItem : map.values()) {
    if((otherItem.price <= item.price + 100)
            && (otherItem.price >= item.price - 100)) {
        otherItem.printItemDetails();
    }
}
```

If you collected the items in a `List` instead of a `Map`, then you would replace `map.values()` in the above with just `list` (or whatever name you use for the `List`).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I got the desired output. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For what you say you want (items with prices near the desired item), a HashMap isn't an efficient datastore.

However, since it sounds like this is your homework, once you use map.get("111") to get your laptop, get the price P, and then iterate over the hashmap to get any item whose price is within your desired delta of P.  The Collections tutorial tells you how to iterate over a collection.